# Overload GraphQL Schema to Support getting a user by username or password

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am trying to create a GraphQL Schema such that a user will be able to find a user by their email or username. Imagine for these purposes one user could have an email that is the username of another user.

My typeDefs look as follows:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    user: User(username: String!)
    user: User(email: String!)
  }
`;
```

Is this a valid Schema? If not how would I change my solution to be valid and solve my problem?

Edit: So I tried to execute the above and I get an error: 'Error: Field "Query.user" can only be defined once.' As I thought I might.

Is there any way to ensure that exactly one of `username` and `email` is null in the following: `user: User(username: String, email: String)`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "overloading" of fields in GraphQL, and no syntax that would support one of two fields being required. An argument is either nullable or non-null, that's it. You can do this:

```
type Query {
  user(username: String, email: String): User
}
```

or this

```
type Query {
  user(filter: UserFilter!): User
}

input UserFilter {
  username: String
  email: String
}
```

and then handle validation (at least one argument is defined but not both) inside your resolver. The only other way to do it would be something like:

```
type Query {
  user(key: UserFilterKey!, value: String!): User
}

enum UserFilterKey {
  username
  email
}
```

But this kind of approach is not very intuitive for anyone consuming the schema. It also only works if the arguments in question have the same type.